# Unable to set the parent datacontext for datatemplate tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Unable to set the parent datacontext for datatemplate tooltip.

Below is the xaml code. Just once combo box and in the combobox datatemplate added textbox.

**Xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Name="UC"
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Width="200" Height="50" ItemsSource="{Binding Coll}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Length}">
                        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=DataContext.ToolTipValue, 
                                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                       AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ViewModel**

```
    private List<string> _coll;

    public List<string> Coll
    {
        get { return _coll; }
        set { _coll = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _ToolTipValue;

    public string ToolTipValue
    {
        get { return _ToolTipValue; }
        set { _ToolTipValue = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _coll = new List<string>(){ "1", "2", "3"};
        _ToolTipValue = "Demo";
    }
```

Can you please help me why DataContext is not set.

Is it binding issue?

Comment: you need to call `ToolTipValue = "something` to trigger it's setter and `OnPropertyChanged`, you should not interact with the private properties.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it, I set value to private field in constructor. It's working fine for combox itemsource

Comment: Agreed, it works. imagine you changing the values later. the private property won't update property changed !

Comment: can u add a little more xaml pls. At least the usercontrol you are refering to

Comment: Just i am trying sample demo, But  couldn't set tooltip text

Comment: Updated Xaml. please refer now

Comment: Content="{Binding Path=DataContext.ToolTipValue, ElementName=UC}"' - not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't need any special things try not to nest the tooltip:

```
<TextBlock ToolTip="{Binding DataContext.ToolTipValue, 
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
           Text="{Binding Length}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Got it, but may I know why it's not working in my code?

Comment: @superuser to be honest .. I got no idea.. :D